# problem hosting a Static page with loopback

Tags: html, rest, loopbackjs

I want to host a static page in loopback. I have added HTML in client dir and removed the default path in server/boot/root.js

But, I have to follow some rules about routes so that I replaced '/api/' to '/' in config.json's restApiRoot. Now I want to host this static HTML page on '/' route. But It gives this error

```
{"success":false,"message":"There is no method to handle GET /"}
```

Also, I tried to set a different path for static page in middleware.json like this,

```
"files": {
    "loopback#static": {
      "paths": [
        "/admin/"
      ],
      "params": "$!../client"
    }
  },
```

Still, this is also not working.
PS: I have added a boot script for following our code of conduct for the response, that's why it's giving this type of response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, LoopBack's REST API handler takes ownership of the entire path namespace it's mounted on. If you mount your REST API at `/api`, then our handler will return 404 whenever a path is not mapped to any remote methods. When you mount your REST API at `/`, the handler will take over the entire HTTP server.

Fortunately, it's possible to disable this behavior via configuration. See `rest. handleUnknownPaths` option in [config.json >> Remoting properties](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/config.json.html#remoting-properties.).

Here is an example showing how to disable this flag in your `server/config.json` file (please note I omitted any other configuration you may already have in that file):

```
{
  "remoting": {
    "rest": {
      "handleUnknownPaths": false
    }
  }
}
```

> I have added a boot script for following our code of conduct for the response, that's why it's giving this type of response.

You may want to set both `errorHandler` and `rest.handleErrors` to false, so that LoopBack does not convert errors to HTTP responses.

Example `server/config.json`:

```
{
  "remoting": {
    "errorHandler": false,
    "rest": {
      "handleErrors": false,
      "handleUnknownPaths": false
    }
  }
}
```

With this setup in place, you can edit `server/middleware.json` and replace the default `strong-error-handler` middleware with your own error-handling implementation (see [Defining middleware >> Path to middleware function](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-middleware.html#path-to-middleware-function).